# Magento2 upgrading to 2.3.3 SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused

Tags: magento2, magento2.3.3

I'm trying to follow the [devdoc instructions](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html) for a CLI upgrade from 2.3.2 to 2.3.3 but I'm getting this Connection refused error partway through the process.

My `app/etc/env.php` looks like this...

```
    'db' => [
        'table_prefix' => '',
        'connection' => [
            'default' => [
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'dbname' => 'my_database_name',
                'username' => 'my_database_user',
                'password' => 'my_database_password',
                'active' => '1'
            ]
        ]
    ],
```

I can connect using these credentials `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -u my_database_user -p my_database_name` fine.

Running a `bin/magento setup:upgrade` gives me....

```
Cache cleared successfully
File system cleanup:
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Amazon
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Composer
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Dotdigitalgroup
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Ebizmarts
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Infortis
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/MSP
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Magento
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Migration
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Symfony
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Temando
/var/www/html/magento2/generated/code/Yotpo
The directory '/var/www/html/magento2/generated/metadata/' doesn't exist - skipping cleanup
Updating modules:
Schema creation/updates:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused
```

I'm really confused by this and how to correct it.

The only other clue I have is that `magento.cron.log` has lines of the form...

```
In Abstract.php line 144:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused


In Abstract.php line 128:

  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Connection refused


queue:consumers:start [--max-messages MAX-MESSAGES] [--batch-size BATCH-SIZE] [--area-code AREA-CODE] [--single-thread] [--pid-file-path PID-FILE-PATH] [--] <consumer>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try increasing a memory limit? php -d memory_limit=4G bin/magento setup:upgrade ?

Comment: restart your all apache server...
and then flush or clear cache.

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% sure mysql is running and testing the connection from the command line works?

mysql -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD -h HOSTNAMEORIP DATABASENAME

My 2.3.3 env.php db section looks like this

```
    'db' => [
    'table_prefix' => '',
    'connection' => [
        'default' => [
            'host' => 'host',
            'dbname' => 'dbname',
            'username' => 'user',
            'password' => 'pass',
            'model' => 'mysql4',
            'engine' => 'innodb',
            'initStatements' => 'SET NAMES utf8;',
            'active' => '1'
        ]
    ]
],
```

Comment: Yes, 100% sure it’s running and those credentials work. In fact, if my credentials in `env.php` are wrong, the upgrade job won’t even start (tried it).

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem after upgrading MySQL to 5.7

Then I copied the site to my local installation and had MySQL 5.7. Still the same error.
[image]

For my local I am using MAMP. MAMP has the option below which was not enabled.
[image]

When I enabled network access, everything worked as expected. 
After some Google Search, I found some config need to be enabled for default mysql installation. Check the following url, "Step 3":
https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Hope this will help you with the problem.